# How to regularise SGD in sklearn by using a gaussian prior with mean different than 0?

Tags: machine-learning, python, least-squares, scikit-learn, regularization

I am using SGDregressor of Sklearn in order to fit a least squares linear regression in an online setting. I would like to use a normal distributed prior with mean 1 for my coefficients. In other words I would like to add the following regularizer term: $\lambda ||w-\frac{1}{d}||_2^2$ where $d$ is the number of coefficients.

With the `penalty` argument I can specify a l2, l1 or both but always with a prior mean of 0.

The closest I could get would be to use elastic net with a regularizer term $\frac{2}{d}$ larger for L1 than L2 regularization. Indeed
$$\begin{align}
reg &= \lambda ||w-\frac{1}{d}||^2\\
&=\lambda w^2 - \frac{2}{d}\lambda w + (const)
\end{align}$$
Minimizing the loss function with this regularizer is equivalent as regularizing using an elastic net with $\lambda_{L1} = 2\lambda_{L2}$ when $w_i <0, \ \forall i$ but not in the general case.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a change of variables to $v = w - \frac1d \mathbf 1$. Since $v^T x = w^T x - \frac1d \sum x_i$, you should also use "fake" labels of $y_i - \frac1d \sum x_i$ to get the right optimization problem. At prediction time, remember to add $\frac1d \sum x_i$ to the output from the model's `predict` method.